# Rviz Status Error in Costmap: Update area outside original area

Tags: mobile-robot, ros, navigation, path-planning, rviz

“update area outside of original map area” is the error I get when visualising the topic /move_base/global_costmap/costmap. The cost map displays correctly, there is nothing on google or the docs to suggest what might cause it except the source code for rviz here where the error originates.'

http://docs.ros.org/en/jade/api/rviz/... at line 506

I tried setting up the height and width parameters in the global costmap common params to the size of the map in pixels (384x384); the map is generated by Gmapping. I read the documentation but couldn't find anything helpful to troubleshoot or what might be causing it.

Comment: It fixed itself, no idea why and how !?